# How does one include sparklines and other per-row graphics in a Google Table (or similar)?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, data-visualization

I have a table that makes extensive use of the features in Google Charts' [Table Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table.html), notably, sorting by selected column and color gradients.

I'd like to add a sparkline column.  Can anyone suggest methods for doing so?  [Google Sparkline](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/imagesparkline.html) doesn't appear to be at all integrable.

The only method I've come up with (I haven't tried it) is to create a set of images and set them as the CSS background, one cell at a time.  Blecch.

I also have a need to show something like a pie chart or stacked bar per row in a column - something that shows gross proportions of the parts of a whole, with three to five parts.  Here also, the Google chart tools don't integrate into Table, AFAICT.

Answers that suggest a different library that doesn't include Google table are fine - as long as the level of effort isn't too much higher, and a similar level of documentation is available.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Larry K regarding remembering the requirement to store/access the set of numbers that represent the points on your sparkline.

In terms of inserting it to the table, consider the [image line charts api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/line_charts.html). You can easily generate sparkline images once you have the relevant set of numbers for them, and can embed the image url into a table cell, allowing it to render by specifying the `allowHtml` option in the table chart.

So, just making a cell with `<img src='google.com?params=2&whatever=3' />` should do the trick.

Comment: Google image charts are unfortunately deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You would write your own [data formatter](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#formatters) to display the sparkline rather than the contents of the cell.

The next issue is to access/store the array of numbers that you want to represent by a sparkline. -- Remember that a Sparkline represents a set of values, it does not represent a single column/value.

There are several ways to solve this problem--eg store the number set as a string; store a key  that would be used to look up the number set; or the formatter could use other values in the same row to determine the number set.

**Added** On second thought, it is not clear if you have access to a generic formatter that can return arbitrary html as the format for the cell's data. I thought you did but perhaps not.

Comment: Perhaps yes - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286368/how-to-write-a-custom-formatter-for-google-datatables-for-use-on-visualisation.  I'm thinking that a custom formatter that uses the image line charts api, as @oli suggests, might do the trick.