# Sparklines in Shiny using gvisTable

Tags: r, google-visualization, shiny, googlevis

I would like to display sparklines in tables `Shiny` displays, using `gvisTable` from the `googleVis` package.

My question is related to this one:

[How does one include sparklines and other per-row graphics in a Google Table (or similar)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124025/how-does-one-include-sparklines-and-other-per-row-graphics-in-a-google-table-or)

For which there is an accepted answer for the javascript version. However, I am not sure how to implement this solution within `Shiny`.