# Google Visualization table chart click and return row / column values not working in Mozilla browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, charts, google-visualization, mozilla

I'm running into a problem with differences between Chrome and Mozilla browsers in the below code.

When you click on a cell the code returns the row / column clicked.  It works fine in Chrome, but when I click a cell in Mozilla nothing happens.

I think it has something to do with this bit of code but I really don't know.

```
var selection = table.getChart().getSelection();
if (selection.length === 0)
  return;

var e = event || window.event;
var cell = e.target; //get selected cell
```

I am referencing this post from a few years ago.  The code in this post works in Chrome works but not in Mozilla, you click and nothing happens.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165281/google-chart-getselection-doesnt-have-column-property/33445620#33445620](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33445620)

Here's my full program.  Any idea how to resolve the Chrome vs Mozilla conflict??

Thank you as always!

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls', 'charteditor']
});

renderChart_onPageLoad();

function renderChart_onPageLoad() {
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawTable();
  }); //END setOnLoadCallback
} //END function renderChart_onEvent

function drawTable() {
  var jsonArray = jsonDataArray_1to1(json);

  //Modify header row to include id and label
  jsonArray = arrayHeaderRow_id_label_date(jsonArray);
  console.log('jsonArray'); console.log(jsonArray);

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonArray, false); // 'false' means that the first row contains labels, not data.
  //console.log('data');
  //console.log(data);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('div_dashboard'));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'div_categoryPicker1',
    'matchType': 'any',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': 0, //Column used in control
      'ui': {
        //'label': 'Actual State:',
        //'labelSeparator': ':',
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowWrapping',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false,
        'allowNone': true
      }
    }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    options: {
      allowHtml: true
    }
  });

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker1], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function() {

    //ORIGINAL from older post https://stackoverflow.com/a/33445620
    var selection = table.getChart().getSelection();
    if (selection.length === 0)
      return;

    var e = event || window.event;
    var cell = e.target; //get selected cell

    document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = "Row: " + selection[0].row + " Column: " + cell.cellIndex;

    //NEW additional requirements

    var tableDataView = table.getDataTable();

    var selectedRow = selection[0].row;
    var selectedCol = cell.cellIndex;

    document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = "selectedRow: " + selectedRow + " selectedCol: " + selectedCol;

    var colID = tableDataView.getColumnId(selectedCol);
    var colLabel = tableDataView.getColumnLabel(selectedCol);

    document.getElementById('output3').innerHTML = "colID: " + colID + " colLabel: " + colLabel;

  });
}





//Library

function jsonDataArray_1to1(json) {
  //DYNAMIC JSON ARRAY

  var dataArray_cln = [];

  //A. The desired table requires the fixed columns of ..... to ..... these are directly taken from the JSON.
  var dataArray_keys = Object.keys(json[0]);

  dataArray_cln.push(dataArray_keys);

  //Add rows 1 to json.length with null values
  var dataArray_rows = json.length;
  var dataArray_cols = dataArray_keys.length;

  for (i = 0; i < dataArray_rows; i++) {
    dataArray_cln.push(Array(dataArray_cols).fill(null));
  }

  //Update array from json data
  for (i = 0; i < dataArray_rows; i++) {
    //[i + 1] because row 0 is the header, push begins with row 1
    //dataArray_cln[row][col]

    //Content in row "i" is positioned into dataArray_cln[row][col] incrementing "j" to pull each key name from dataArray_keys
    for (var j = 0; j < dataArray_keys.length; j++) {
      eval('dataArray_cln[i + 1][' + j + '] = json[i].' + dataArray_keys[j]);
    }
  }

  //console.log(dataArray_cln);
  return dataArray_cln;
}

function arrayHeaderRow_id_label_date(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
    var valueOrig = arr[0][i];
    var valueNew;
    switch (true) {
      case valueOrig === 'wd':
        valueNew = JSON.parse('{"id":"' + valueOrig + '", "label":"' + valueOrig + '", "type": "date"}');
        break;
      default:
        valueNew = JSON.parse('{"id":"' + valueOrig + '", "label": "' + valueOrig + '"}');
    }
    arr[0][i] = valueNew;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id='div_dashboard'>
  <div id='div_categoryPicker1'></div>
  <div id='div_table'></div>
</div>

<div id="output1"></div><br/>
<div id="output2"></div><br/>
<div id="output3"></div><br/>

<script>
  var json = [{
      "division": "GS",
      "m1": 100.000000,
      "m2": 100.000000,
      "m3": null,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": null,
      "m6": null,
      "m7": null,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "GS",
      "m1": 100.000000,
      "m2": 90.000000,
      "m3": null,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": null,
      "m6": null,
      "m7": null,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "PS",
      "m1": null,
      "m2": null,
      "m3": 100.000000,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": 100.000000,
      "m6": 100.000000,
      "m7": 75.000000,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "PS",
      "m1": null,
      "m2": null,
      "m3": 100.000000,
      "m4": 100.000000,
      "m5": 100.000000,
      "m6": 100.000000,
      "m7": 80.000000,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    }
  ];

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google's table chart produces a normal html `<table>`.

instead of using google's `'select'` event,
we can assign a standard `'click'` event to the table's `<td>` elements.

wait until the table chart's `'ready'` event fires.
then assign click handler to the cells.

to get column index --> `cell.cellIndex`
to row index --> `cell.closest('tr').rowIndex`

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function() {
  var container = document.getElementById(table.getContainerId());
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('TD'), function(cell) {
    cell.addEventListener('click', selectCell);
  });

  function selectCell(sender) {
    var cell = sender.target;
    var row = cell.closest('tr');
    document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = "Row: " + (row.rowIndex - 1) + " Column: " + cell.cellIndex;

    //NEW additional requirements

    var tableDataView = table.getDataTable();

    var selectedRow = row.rowIndex - 1;  // adjust for header row (-1)
    var selectedCol = cell.cellIndex;

    document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = "selectedRow: " + selectedRow + " selectedCol: " + selectedCol;

    var colID = tableDataView.getColumnId(selectedCol);
    var colLabel = tableDataView.getColumnLabel(selectedCol);

    document.getElementById('output3').innerHTML = "colID: " + colID + " colLabel: " + colLabel;
  }

});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls', 'charteditor']
});

renderChart_onPageLoad();

function renderChart_onPageLoad() {
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawTable();
  }); //END setOnLoadCallback
} //END function renderChart_onEvent

function drawTable() {
  var jsonArray = jsonDataArray_1to1(json);

  //Modify header row to include id and label
  jsonArray = arrayHeaderRow_id_label_date(jsonArray);
  console.log('jsonArray'); console.log(jsonArray);

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonArray, false); // 'false' means that the first row contains labels, not data.
  //console.log('data');
  //console.log(data);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('div_dashboard'));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'div_categoryPicker1',
    'matchType': 'any',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': 0, //Column used in control
      'ui': {
        //'label': 'Actual State:',
        //'labelSeparator': ':',
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowWrapping',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false,
        'allowNone': true
      }
    }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    options: {
      allowHtml: true
    }
  });

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker1], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function() {
    var container = document.getElementById(table.getContainerId());
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('TD'), function(cell) {
      cell.addEventListener('click', selectCell);
    });

    function selectCell(sender) {
      var cell = sender.target;
      var row = cell.closest('tr');
      document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = "Row: " + (row.rowIndex - 1) + " Column: " + cell.cellIndex;

      //NEW additional requirements

      var tableDataView = table.getDataTable();

      var selectedRow = row.rowIndex - 1;  // adjust for header row (-1)
      var selectedCol = cell.cellIndex;

      document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = "selectedRow: " + selectedRow + " selectedCol: " + selectedCol;

      var colID = tableDataView.getColumnId(selectedCol);
      var colLabel = tableDataView.getColumnLabel(selectedCol);

      document.getElementById('output3').innerHTML = "colID: " + colID + " colLabel: " + colLabel;
    }

  });

}





//Library

function jsonDataArray_1to1(json) {
  //DYNAMIC JSON ARRAY

  var dataArray_cln = [];

  //A. The desired table requires the fixed columns of ..... to ..... these are directly taken from the JSON.
  var dataArray_keys = Object.keys(json[0]);

  dataArray_cln.push(dataArray_keys);

  //Add rows 1 to json.length with null values
  var dataArray_rows = json.length;
  var dataArray_cols = dataArray_keys.length;

  for (i = 0; i < dataArray_rows; i++) {
    dataArray_cln.push(Array(dataArray_cols).fill(null));
  }

  //Update array from json data
  for (i = 0; i < dataArray_rows; i++) {
    //[i + 1] because row 0 is the header, push begins with row 1
    //dataArray_cln[row][col]

    //Content in row "i" is positioned into dataArray_cln[row][col] incrementing "j" to pull each key name from dataArray_keys
    for (var j = 0; j < dataArray_keys.length; j++) {
      eval('dataArray_cln[i + 1][' + j + '] = json[i].' + dataArray_keys[j]);
    }
  }

  //console.log(dataArray_cln);
  return dataArray_cln;
}

function arrayHeaderRow_id_label_date(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
    var valueOrig = arr[0][i];
    var valueNew;
    switch (true) {
      case valueOrig === 'wd':
        valueNew = JSON.parse('{"id":"' + valueOrig + '", "label":"' + valueOrig + '", "type": "date"}');
        break;
      default:
        valueNew = JSON.parse('{"id":"' + valueOrig + '", "label": "' + valueOrig + '"}');
    }
    arr[0][i] = valueNew;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id='div_dashboard'>
  <div id='div_categoryPicker1'></div>
  <div id='div_table'></div>
</div>

<div id="output1"></div><br/>
<div id="output2"></div><br/>
<div id="output3"></div><br/>

<script>
  var json = [{
      "division": "GS",
      "m1": 100.000000,
      "m2": 100.000000,
      "m3": null,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": null,
      "m6": null,
      "m7": null,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "GS",
      "m1": 100.000000,
      "m2": 90.000000,
      "m3": null,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": null,
      "m6": null,
      "m7": null,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "PS",
      "m1": null,
      "m2": null,
      "m3": 100.000000,
      "m4": null,
      "m5": 100.000000,
      "m6": 100.000000,
      "m7": 75.000000,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    },
    {
      "division": "PS",
      "m1": null,
      "m2": null,
      "m3": 100.000000,
      "m4": 100.000000,
      "m5": 100.000000,
      "m6": 100.000000,
      "m7": 80.000000,
      "m8": null,
      "m9": null,
      "m10": null,
      "m11": null,
      "m12": null,
    }
  ];

</script>
```

Comment: Absolutely!  Thank you once again for your help.