# google charts - custom formatter to show elapsed time?

Tags: google-visualization

I have database information showing elapsed time for various program executions. I was wondering if there was a way to use google charts formatter object on a stepped area chart object's y axis to show the time as "HH::MM::SS".  I don't have information on the start time for each execution, just the elapsed time. My only thought so far is to convert the time values into hours. Example 1h:20m becomes 1.3 hours. I would prefer to show it as "HH::MM::SS"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6596629/76677) provided by [@broofa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109538/broofa)